# rvest won't pull text after "<" even though it is part of the string

Tags: html, rvest

Website I'm trying to pull from: http://goodcompanies.com/company/31-bits/

Value I'm trying to scrape `"Most <$100"`:

```
<div class="company-info-section no-flex-grow no-flex-shink">
    <h4 class="all-caps title-line-right no-margin company-section-title">
        <span>Price Range</span>
    </h4>
    <b>Most <$100</b>
</div>
```

Code I'm using:

```
   html <- read_html(http://goodcompanies.com/company/31-bits/)

   info <- html %>%
       html_nodes('.company-info-section') %>%
       html_text() %>%
       .[1]
```

I get: `"\n\t\t\n\t\t\tPrice Range\n\t\t\n\t\tMost \n\t"`

But what I want and should get is: `"\n\t\t\n\t\t\tPrice Range\n\t\t\n\t\tMost < $100\n\t"`

It seems like the fact that in the actual HTML there isn't a space between the `<` and the `$` is causing the issue. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

The space isn’t the issue; the actual issue is that the website is simply using invalid HTML: `<` in HTML code must be escaped (e.g. as `&lt;`), and the website isn’t doing that.

Unfortunately rvest appears to cope badly with invalid HTML. The best solution would be to find an HTML parser that can deal with messy/invalid HTML. Unfortunately I don’t know any for R.

A hacky solution would be to download the page into a character string, fix the problem (i.e. perform a `gubs('<$', '&lt;$', page_text)` or similar), and *then* pass it to rvest.